# Unable to change Dialog Background color Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-theme

In my code when ever dialog is displayed it darkens out like having a grey color I have specified a theme by setting windowBackground to white but its not working.

**My theme**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchStyle</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/MyAlertDialogTheme</item>


    </style>

 <style name="MyAlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    </style>
```

[image: Dialog Image]

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
```

with

```
<item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
```

Comment: delete the other 4 items

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it programmatically

```
dialog.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to change dialog background color

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/DialogBackgroundColor</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogBackgroundColor" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```